# Sniff HTTP packets for GET and POST requests from an application

Tags: http, wireshark

I am coding an SEO tool in C# for doing keyword research. I need to make calls to Google Adword keyword tool. Now I know some tools which are doing the same already.

I just need to decipher what they are doing. I tried using Wireshark but it's very complex to get the actual POST data using Wireshark.

I tried using fiddler on IE but seems like too many Javascript requests are made which confuses fiddler a lot.

If I can just find out the exact requests the other tool is making I think my job is done. How can I do this?

Comment: Getting HTTP post data is very easy with Wireshark.  For starters, make sure you set a display filter of "HTTP" so you see only HTTP-related packets and nothing else.  Then you can look inside of the packets as needed.  Wireshark separates the post data from the HTTP headers for you.

Comment: @remy do you have any tut link for this? Iam fiddling with it over past 2 days with little success.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Put `http.request.method == "POST"` in the display filter of wireshark to only show POST requests.  Click on the packet, then expand the Hypertext Transfer Protocol field.  The POST data will be right there on top.

Comment: If you set the display filter to just `HTTP` by itself, then you can see GETs and POSTs together.

Comment: use `http.request` to get GET n POST calls.

Comment: Remember to use uppercase BTW.

Comment: Yes, you get the entire packet, parsed out.

Comment: No it won't show post data over https. It shows encrypted data application

Comment: You may also want to combine it with `tcp contains "something`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some sort of network sniffer if you want to get at this sort of data and you're likely to run into the same problem (pulling out the relevant data from the overall network traffic) with those that you do now with Wireshark.